# Moment JS Setting date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a `datetime` string from which I am creating a `start_time` and `end_time` variable.

**Expected Output:**
`start_time` should be exactly 2 days from now with the time taken from `datetime` string and `end_time` is exactly 3 hours from `start_time`.

**Code**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const time = "2019-12-13T05:30:00+08:00"
  const date = moment(time);
  const h = date.hour();
  const m = date.minutes();
  const s = date.seconds();

  const from = moment().add(2, 'days');
  var start_time = from.clone().hour(h).minute(m).second(s);
  var end_time = start_time.clone().add(3, 'hours');

  // start_time = start_time.toISOString();
  // end_time = end_time.toISOString();

  console.log(start_time); // Expected: "2019-12-15T05:30:00+08:00"
  console.log(end_time); // Expected: "2019-12-15T08:30:00+08:00"
</script>
```

**Expected Result:**

start_time: "2019-12-15T05:30:00+08:00"

end_time: "2019-12-15T08:30:00+08:00"

**Current Result:**

start_time: "2019-12-14T21:30:00.604Z"

end_time: "2019-12-15T00:30:00.604Z"

Any idea on how to properly format the date in this case to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using different time zone. The input is +8 timezone and the output is UTC

If you added `.format()`, you will see that you actually have the correct value.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const time = "2019-12-13T05:30:00+08:00"
  const date = moment(time);
  const h = date.hour();
  const m = date.minutes();
  const s = date.seconds();

  const from = moment().add(2, 'days');
  var start_time = from.clone().hour(h).minute(m).second(s);
  var end_time = start_time.clone().add(3, 'hours');

  // start_time = start_time.toISOString();
  // end_time = end_time.toISOString();

  // added .format()
  console.log(start_time.format()); // Expected: "2019-12-15T05:30:00+08:00"
  console.log(end_time.format()); // Expected: "2019-12-15T08:30:00+08:00"
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var start_time:moment().add(2,'days');
var end_time:moment().add(2,'days').add(3,'hours')
```